# Is it possible for a pitcher to hit a homerun in RBI Baseball?

Tags: rbi-baseball

In the original RBI Baseball game on NES all the pitchers had the same batting stats; a 150 batting average and 0 home runs (I think).  A friend of mine has always claimed that he has hit a home run with a pitcher.

Is it possible to determine how far a pitcher can hit the ball and if they are capable of hitting a home run?

Answer (score 2):

According to this fan based [website](http://dee-nee.com/rbi/faq.shtml#PITCHERHR):

**Is it possible to hit a home run with the pitcher?**

> Apparently, it is. I have received more than a few emails and read messages on my forums confirming the pitcher homer. The people on the forums are reliable folks and I am certain they are telling the truth, so it is possible. In every case I've read, the ball is lined down the left/right field line and goes through the top of the wall (aka the wallzie)>. That being said, none of the Dee-Nee crew or anyone I know personally has ever gone yard with the pitcher. But we will...

Just some additional information on the pitchers when it comes to batting as far as determining the hitting of the ball:

> all pitchers have the exact same batting characteristics

I'm not 100% sure how reliable the resource is, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of other information out there for this game that I have found.

Answer (score 1):

A pitcher can definitely score a home run... although maybe not in the usual way. I was curious so I spent about an hour looking at various videos of the game, and while I did not come across a straight home-run, I did find this:

There were also a few videos of what was either a glitch or cheat that seemed to turn contact into a home run.

Comment: Absence of evidence is not proof of absence, but our lack of ability to find something does have certain implications.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I recall most of the circumstances.  Although I almost always
played a 2 player game because 1 player isn't interesting, I was bored so I played a
1 player game against Detroit.  I can't remember who I used...probably St. Louis...

Anyway, my starter (Tudor?) was worn down and I was lobbing meat pitches straight
down the middle.  Doyle Alexander hit a weak fly down the left field line and it had
just enough juice to make it pass through the bottom of the fence.

Now mind you, I've played thousands of games in RBI baseball and saw this only once.
I could hard believe it and my buddies, to this day, claim I'm lying.